# ASP.NET Boilerplate available list of exceptions and returned HTTP Status Codes

Tags: api, exception, asp.net-core, http-status-codes, aspnetboilerplate

I am building an API with ASP.NET Boilerplate and they abstract out the error handling and returning of the HTTP Status Codes.
I have looked through the documentation and it only mentions UserFriendlyException and AbpValidationException.

What are the other available exceptions I can throw with ASP.NET Boilerplate and its corresponding HTTP response codes that it returns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below are the exceptions and the correspondings status code according to the [GetStatusCode() method](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.Web.Api/WebApi/ExceptionHandling/AbpApiExceptionFilterAttribute.cs#L114):

> - Abp.AbpException - 500
> - Abp.AbpInitializationException - 500
> - Abp.Authorization.AbpAuthorizationException - could be 403 or 401
> - Abp.BackgroundJobs.BackgroundJobException - 500
> - Abp.Domain.Entities.EntityNotFoundException - 404
> - Abp.Domain.Uow.AbpDbConcurrencyException - 500
> - Abp.Runtime.Validation.AbpValidationException - 400
> - Abp.UI.UserFriendlyException - 500
> - Abp.WebApi.Client.AbpRemoteCallException - 500

```
protected virtual HttpStatusCode GetStatusCode(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is Abp.Authorization.AbpAuthorizationException)
        {
            return AbpSession.UserId.HasValue
                ? HttpStatusCode.Forbidden
                : HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        }

        if (context.Exception is AbpValidationException)
        {
            return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        }

        if (context.Exception is EntityNotFoundException)
        {
            return HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        }

        return HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }
```

[Available exceptions from docs](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/api-docs/html/T_Abp_AbpException.htm#fullInheritance)

Answer (score 2):

The list of available exceptions are;

- AbpException
- UserFriendlyException
- AbpRemoteCallException
- AbpValidationException
- BackgroundJobException
- EntityNotFoundException
- AbpAuthorizationException
- AbpDbConcurrencyException
- AbpInitializationException